# HTML Multiple Tables Spacing

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have 2 tables wrapped inside a Div:

```
<div class = "main" id = "mainDiv">
    <table id = "one">
    1
    </table>

    <table id = "two">
    2
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I displays these two tables side by side with 5 px apart from each other?
Is there something like "cellspacing" I can use but for tables?

Comment: There is such a thing as [`display:inline-table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/249mp1b8/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure is incorrect, it should be like this :

```
<div class = "main" id = "mainDiv">
    <table id = "one">
       <tr>
         <td>1</td>
       </tr> 
    </table>

    <table id = "two">
       <tr>
         <td>2</td>
       </tr> 
    </table>
</div>
```

And you could change the `display:table;` of the table to `display:inline-table;` to align them on one line.

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/2ornbfd3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use css and you can make it so that it's responsive, Check out this code for 2 columns. In this code it is 2 equal width columns at 49.2%. If you want a different split change that.

```css
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF TWO  */
.span_2_of_2 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
 width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col { 
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
 <div class="col span_1_of_2">
 This is column 1
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_2">
 This is column 2
 </div>
</div>
```